# Is it possible to force silver searcher to search through files on list or chain searches?

Tags: ag

To print only names of files which match search there is:
`ag -l`

What should I use if I want to grep only through files from list? Or maybe is it possible to chain searches in this way?

Answer (score 3):

From this page I gleamed both the fact that the `ag -l` returns a list of file names and that `ag` takes a stdin of files. That got me thinking about another way that has worked out pretty great for me. Wanted to share

```
ag -l <first_search> | xargs ag -l <second_search> | xargs ag -l ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use std input redirection:

```
ag "SEARCH_PATTERN" < file1, file,2, file3...
```

Or use a wild card search for target files with the -g option. The template would look like this:

```
ag -g "FILE_PATTERN" "SEARCH_PATTERN"
```

So an example would be as follows:

```
   ag -G '.*.txt' "pattern"
```

Or feed files or search patterns into ag from a .txt file containing a list of entries, using a shell's for loop; for example:

```
while IFS= read -r patterns; do ag -o "$patterns" ~/somewhere ; done < names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run:

```bash
ag <pattern> <file1> <file2> <...fileN>
```

Example:

```
$ ag 'todo' a b
a
59: // todo - demo 1
92: // todo - demo 2

b
15:  // TODO - demo 3
```